# How can I compute the necessary memory limit for my Fortran code?

Tags: memory-management, fortran, fortran90

I have a Fortran 90 code. I have tried to allocate a `r(5000000,5000,3)` array with real numbers in my code. After compiling with double precision (I am using gfortran compiler), I received this error:

***Operating system error: cannot allocate memory.
Allocation would exceed memory limit***

My computer has a 16GB RAM.
What should I do for this problem?
I do not know what to do.

Comment: Assuming that you want to allocate double precision floating point numbers, you are requesting 600 GB of RAM. Do you really need it that much memory? Consider writing the data to a file and read in variables you need on the fly. 5000000*5000*3*8 byte = 600 GB

Comment: Hi, I need that much memory. Actually i cannot understand this sentence " Consider writing the data to a file and read in variables you need on the fly"? What do you mean by saying "on the fly"?

Comment: I meant that you could write the array to a file and read the parts that you need into your program. If you can‘t afford more RAM and if it‘s not possible to rewrite your program s.t. it uses less memory then this is propably your only option.

Comment: Hi nameiki. I compiled my Fortran code in a server that has a 128 GB of RAM and 64 cores. and my code can run successfully now. But the server has a 128 GB of RAM not a 600GB of RAM !!!!. How can it be possible?!!! If you can explain, I will be so happy.

Comment: It is possible to use more memory than your physical built in memory. This is called swapping. The hard drive is used to extend your memory. It is very slow because read and write speeds are much higher in RAM compared to an HDD/SSD. When you are compiling the code on your machine, your operating system complains because it doesn't want to or can't provide 580 GB of swap memory and the compilation fails. On the server, the operating system seems to be able to provide 472 GB of swap RAM and you can compile and run the program.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling x64 code?

Comment: Also, if you use the default `real` and not `double precision` or `real` of a higher kind, it will be just 300 GB, not 600 GB so more likely to the swap at the large machine. Large memory requirements are one of the reasons one may want to do distributed memory parallelization on a cluster - e.g., using MPI or coarrays.

Comment: Hi nameiki. Fisrt of all, Thank you very much for your clear explanation !!!. But, when I type this command in linux terminal in the server --> "grep Swap /proc/meminfo". Result is :  Swap Cached:            0 kB ,  SwapTotal:       18975740 kB ,  SwapFree:       18975740 kB. According to this information, swap dimension is approximately 19GB. So, 128Gb+19GB=147 GB --> 600GB-147Gb=453 GB WHERE IS the 453 GB ?!!!.

Comment: What is the operation you plan to do with your array? do you need the whole array at once? Can you come up with an algorithm that operates on a portion of the array at a time?

Comment: one question: Are you sure your matrix doesn't have many zeros (or equal value values)? In some numerical methods (ex: finite elements) giant matrices appear, but since they have many zeros, one stores them in CRS (sparse) format (it does not store zeros)